# OpenSSLSocketImpl.getSession crash

Tags: android, ssl, crash

on some devices i get the crash below:

// the crash info

> SIGABRT
>
> ## 00    pc 00041300    /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12) [armeabi-v7a::1b317667710e940729198acd09513c97]
>
> ## 01    pc 000401b5    /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32) [armeabi-v7a::1b317667710e940729198acd09513c97]
>
> ## 02    pc 0001c893    /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10) [armeabi-v7a::1b317667710e940729198acd09513c97]
>
> ## 03    pc 00019af1    /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34) [armeabi-v7a::1b317667710e940729198acd09513c97]
>
> ## 04    pc 000176b8    /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4) [armeabi-v7a::1b317667710e940729198acd09513c97]
>
> ## 05    pc 0001b553    /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_fatal+16) [armeabi-v7a::1b317667710e940729198acd09513c97]
>
> ## 06    pc 0001b56b    /system/lib/libc.so (__fortify_chk_fail+18) [armeabi-v7a::1b317667710e940729198acd09513c97]
>
> ## 07    pc 00046315    /system/lib/libc.so (__FD_SET_chk+24) [armeabi-v7a::1b317667710e940729198acd09513c97]
>
> ## 08    pc 000092f5    /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so [armeabi-v7a::3bdb8758762753b0649e6940a3fc1a62] java:
>
> com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.waitForHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:629)
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getSession(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:793)
>   com.thirdparty.afinal.utils.HttpsHelper$a.createSocket(SourceFile:786)
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:170)
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:366)
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:596)
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:517)
>   com.thirdparty.afinal.f.c.a(SourceFile:80)
>   com.thirdparty.afinal.f.c.b(SourceFile:117)
>   com.thirdparty.afinal.c.d$2.call(SourceFile:146)
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

//the code is as below

private static final class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

```
    private KeyStore mKeystore;

    public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);
        mKeystore = truststore;
    }

    final static HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new StrictHostnameVerifier();

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {

        if (autoClose) {
            socket.close();
        }

        SSLCertificateSocketFactory sslSocketFactory =
                (SSLCertificateSocketFactory) SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getDefault(0);
        try {
            sslSocketFactory.setTrustManagers(new TrustManager[] { new MyX509TrustManager(mKeystore)});
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        @SuppressLint("SSLCertificateSocketFactoryCreateSocket")
        SSLSocket ssl = (SSLSocket)sslSocketFactory.createSocket(InetAddress.getByName(host), port);


        if (socket instanceof SSLSocket) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH
                    && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                ssl.setEnabledProtocols(ssl.getSupportedProtocols());
            }
        }

        sslSocketFactory.setHostname(ssl, host);

        SSLSession session = ssl.getSession();
        if (!hostnameVerifier.verify(host, session)){
            throw new SSLPeerUnverifiedException("Cannot verify hostname: " + host + " peer=" + session.getPeerHost());
        }

        return ssl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `ssl.setEnabledProtocols(getSupportedProtocols());`: don't do this. It is radically insecure.

Answer (score 0):

Your app maybe trying to create too many socket connections at once.

`Android` has a limitation (no more than 1024) on the number of file descriptors per app.